# java.util.NoSuchElementException Error

Tags: java, readfile

I try to read a whole line from text file and display them in different way. For example,

```
    123456J;Gabriel;12/12/1994;67;67;89;
```

But the result in console would be like :

```
    123456J Gabriel 72(which is average of three numbers)
```

Here are my codes :

```
    public class Student{

String adminNo;
String name;
GregorianCalendar birthDate;
int test1,test2,test3;

public Student(String adminNo,String name,String birthDate,int test1, int test2, int test3){
    this.adminNo = adminNo;
    this.name = name;
    this.birthDate = MyCalendar.convertDate(birthDate);
    this.test1 = test1;
    this.test2 = test2;
    this.test3 = test3;
}

public Student(String studentRecord){
    String strBirthDate;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(studentRecord);
    sc.useDelimiter(";");
    adminNo = sc.next();
    name = sc.next();
    strBirthDate = sc.next();
    birthDate = MyCalendar.convertDate(strBirthDate.toString());
    test1 = sc.nextInt();
    test2 = sc.nextInt();
    test3 = sc.nextInt();
}

public int getAverage(){ 
    return (( test1 + test2 + test3 ) / 3 ) ;
}

public String toString(){
    return (adminNo + " " + name + " " + getAverage());
}

public static void main(String [] args){

    Student s = new Student ("121212A", "Tan Ah Bee", "12/12/92", 67, 72, 79);
    System.out.println(s);

    String fileName = "student.txt";
    try{
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(fr);

        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            Student stud = new Student(sc.nextLine());
            System.out.println(stud.toString());
        }

        fr.close();
    }catch(FileNotFoundException exception){
        System.out.println("File " + fileName + " was not found");
    }catch(IOException exception){
        System.out.println(exception);
    }
}
```

And the errors :

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at Student.<init>(Student.java:24)
at Student.main(Student.java:52)
```

But I am getting **java.util.NoSuchElementException** error. Am I missing something? It works just now but out of sudden, there comes an error. I have no idea why.

Any help would be appreciated Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you print the stack trace or the line on which you are getting the exception?

Comment: You are calling next() on Scanner 5-6 times, are you sure that every line has those many elements? Can you print the line (studentRecord) in that constructor?

Comment: Ya, there's 6 info from each line. How to print the line in constructor?

Comment: System.out.println(studentRecord); // put this as a first line in that constructor. And when you get the exception, check the value of studentRecord.

Comment: Ya, there's nothing went wrong and I've no idea why I keep getting error and it was fine like few hours ago

Comment: What u  meant by `few hours ago`? Did u made any update?

Comment: Ya I added some array list then I extends some subclasses and everything was messed up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can modify Student constructor to something like below to check what is the line when exception occured.

```
public Student(String studentRecord){
    String strBirthDate;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(studentRecord);
    sc.useDelimiter(";");

    try {
         adminNo = sc.next();
         name = sc.next();
         strBirthDate = sc.next();
         birthDate = MyCalendar.convertDate(strBirthDate.toString());
         test1 = sc.nextInt();
         test2 = sc.nextInt();
         test3 = sc.nextInt();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException exception)
        System.out.println("NoSuchElementException, the line was: " + studentRecord);
    }
}
```

Comment: I getting this : NoSuchElementException, the line was: 031234F;Michael Tan;01/08/1980;60;70;98
031234F;Michael Tan;01/08/1980;60;70;98 0
NoSuchElementException, the line was: 123456U;Gabriel;12/12/1987;56;67;78
123456U;Gabriel;12/12/1987;56;67;78 null 0
NoSuchElementException, the line was: 
null null 0
And I am totally lost

Comment: Okay, so you've got two records in one line. You have to brake it in source file.

Comment: Oh I solved already. There's an empty rows inside the text file. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Before you call next...() on the Scanner, please make sure that the Scanner actually has the element(s) to avoid that exception.